# Symfony enviar opciones a otro formulario anidado

Tags: symfony5

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    $respuestas = $options['respuesta'];
    
    if($respuestas == 0){
        $builder
        ->add('email', EmailType::class, array(
            'required'=>true,
            'attr'=> array('class'=> 'form-control', 'maxlength'=>250 )
        ))
        ->add('persona', PersonaType::class )
        
    ;
    }
```

Tengo el formulario persona que esta anidado a usuario
->add('persona', Persona1Type::class ) quiero mandarle array $options pero al momento de querer

```
->add('persona', Persona1Type::class, [], array($options['numpais']) )
```

no recibe nada el formulario